# Scala Cats: How to test logging vs how to log in production code

Tags: logging, scala-cats, tagless-final

Could you give me a tagless-final version in Scala, of a logging implementation that is easily testable in unit tests but runs with slf4j or similar frameworks in production?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a skeleton I worked out for myself](https://gist.github.com/kovacshuni/d905d6e587093e8091705445b6b289df).

Tests are written with cats' Writer monad.

Todo: write it for something else than `Id`. What if you need to test errors meanwhile.